# Location Tracking, Doze, AppStandby

Tags: android, location, android-doze, android-appstandby

I've implemented Background Location Tracking using IntentService. I'm able to receive Location points in Foreground Mode. But when a device is locked or after some time app killed, I'm not able to receive location points. How can I handle Doze & AppStandby while tracking the location of a device in the background?

I don't want to run foreground service all the time. Any solution for Background Continuous Location Tracking with handling Doze and AppStandby?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/googlecodelabs/background-location-updates-android-o for reference.

Comment: Don't know if it works. And don't have capabilities to check it right now. But maybe it will help https://github.com/BlackBlind567/Location_Updates-Background_Foreground/tree/master Please, let me know if it works

Comment: I also can make it working by implementing foreground service (with sticky notification) which I don't need to implement. I need only a background service.

Answer (score 4):

You can implement custom locationlistener or FusedLocationProviderApi ([fused link](https://developers.google.com/location-context/fused-location-provider)) as per fused documentation

> The fused location provider manages the underlying location
>   technologies, such as GPS and Wi-Fi.

I implemented the scenario that's not approximately same to yours but in that I had condition to pick targeted location if internet is not available so, i implemented my own Listener that you can find from ([here](https://gist.github.com/AliAzaz/5d9e2cfcf95a3335917de11d44e19a4a)) which is connected to the Bind Service.

You also have to implement the location listener with the use of background service. and for the doze you can programmatically turn it off for this app [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52033875/9764941).

Comment: I'm using I'm using github.com/googlecodelabs/background-location-updates-android-o for reference

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fusedLocationClient API as given in this [link](https://github.com/BlackBlind567/Location_Updates-Background_Foreground/tree/master) then i request you to change your dependencies use Google play services as they provide more feasible and accurate location than fusedLocation API's by android. you can refer the documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) and also they provide a solution for your problem using background location tracking

Comment: I'm using fused location APIs. This is working perfectly but in the case of doze, I'm not receiving Locations.

Comment: I'm using github.com/googlecodelabs/background-location-updates-android-o for reference